# How to scroll with a trackBar between 3000 images ? getting out of memory exception after some scrolling

Tags: c#, winforms

at the top of form1

```
private List<string> files = new List<string>();

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    files = Directory.GetFiles(@"D:\Download Images", "*").ToList();
    pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(files[0]);
    trackBar1.Maximum = files.Count - 1;
}
```

and the scroll event

```
private void trackBar1_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        // Adjust the index because the trackBar is 1-based, and the list is 0-based.
        int index = trackBar1.Value - 1;
        if (index >= 0 && index < files.Count)
        {
            // Dispose of the current image to free memory.
            if (pictureBox1.Image != null)
            {
                pictureBox1.Image.Dispose();
                pictureBox1.Image = null;
            }

            // Load the new image.
            using (var tempImage = Image.FromFile(files[index]))
            {
                pictureBox1.Image = new Bitmap(tempImage);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (OutOfMemoryException)
    {
        // Handle the out of memory exception
        MessageBox.Show("An error occurred due to insufficient memory. Please try again.", "Memory Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}
```

after scrolling fast or slow many times it's throwing the message in the catch part.

maybe i should calculate first the whole images in the List files size and then to calculate how many images i can load to memory each time and then use some pooling technique ?

not sure how to handle it.

Comment: What compiler options are you using.  When you are getting out of memory I suggest using x64 mode.

Comment: Set `TrackBar.Minimum = 0` and  `TrackBar.Maximum = files.Count - 1 ` beforehand. Then, you just need `pictureBox1.Image?.Dispose(); pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(files[trackBar1.Value])), true, false);` -- If you keep the Diagnostic Tools open in the meanwhile, you should see the memory usage increase while you're fast scrolling, then plummet to lower a level when you give it a break (unless you cause memory pressure, then this happens at any time) -- Note that also the size of an (quite large) image can cause an `OutOfMemoryException`

Comment: There is no obvious memory leak I can spot. Check that you are running in x64-mode, you need to be much more careful with things like memory fragmentation in 32bit mode. A memory profiler should also help, especially with a fairly simple and reproducible issue like this.

Comment: Why are you creating a new Bitmap from the tempImage? Can't you just assign tempImage to pictureBox1.Image? And do you really need to show intermediate images while the operator is still scrolling the trackbar? If this is not necessary, consider to update the image after the operator stops scrolling. If some feedback is needed, consider to show the filename as a context menu during the scrolling instead of the image

Answer (score 0):

One way I was able to reproduce a `System.OutOfMemoryException` is to try and read a file in the UI thread while it's in the process of being copied on a background worker. This suggests that you may get this error if you try and scroll to a file being currently being accessed on a different thread perhaps.

It also seemed significant that I could cause a purported `System.OutOfMemoryException` with just a single file in memory, somewhat ruling out the large set of 3000 images being the issue in and of itself.

[image: successful load]

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();            

        buttonLoad.Click += async(sender, e) =>
        {
            // D:\Github\stackoverflow\induce-memory-error\induce-memory-error\bin\Debug\net8.0-windows\Images
            var srce = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Images", "Image.01.jpg");
            var dest = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Images", "Image.01.Copy.jpg");
            if(radioButtonSafe.Checked) 
            {
                await Task.Run(() => File.Copy(srce, dest, overwrite: true));
                pictureBox1.Image?.Dispose();
                pictureBox1.Image = Bitmap.FromFile(dest);
            }
            else
            {
                _ = Task.Run(() => File.Copy(srce, dest, overwrite: true));
                pictureBox1.Image?.Dispose();
                pictureBox1.Image = Bitmap.FromFile(dest);
            }
        };
    }        
}
```

[image: exception]

Comment: [Clone](https://github.com/IVSoftware/induce-memory-error.git)